# How to animate a circle in a rectangle in After Effects?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, google-material-design

I've been trying to recreate this simple effect in After Effects, but with no luck so far[image]

I'm fairly certain I have to work with a circular mask, but I have no idea how to make it work like in the example above. There are some tutorials that deal with masks, but none that deal specifically with Material Design animations in After Effects.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd maybe change the title to something like: "How to animate circle inside a rectangle". The "Material design touch animation" seems a bit too broad, if someone is meant to find this question ever. Aren't there many types of animations in material design? I kinda feel like you've been brainwashed with the marketing term "material design".  As you said, there are plenty of masking tutorials and I'm not sure what more you need. Circle shape with a scale animation and a rectangular mask. That's all you really need ( or as @Naty said, a separate comp. ).

Comment: You're right. These animations weren't invented with Material Design. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For fun see [this](http://webglplayground.net/saved/Aev_5qa_YW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to work with a composition within a composition.

1. Create a small composition that only has the button, there make a shape layer of your circle and enlarge it until it leaves the margins of the composition and you reach the desired animation with opacity, motion blur, etc.
2. Place this small composition into the bigger "screen" composition.

Otherwise make a Track Matte - [read about it here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9657/how-to-mask-an-animated-layer-in-after-effects)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That would work, but the options are fairly limited. What I'm looking to do is filling the white canvas below with a grey touch animation and I think masks would work best.![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/SRv4wl3.jpg

Comment: edited my answwe hope it helps